# Vue.js - Ошибка при попытке распарсить API

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Пытаюсь собрать информацию с сайта Hacker News с помощью Algolia API

```
<div v-for="(story, idx) in stories" :key="idx">
  <h2>{{ story }}</h2>
</div>

...

axios.get("http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story")
  .then(response => {
    this.stories = response;
  })
```

Возвращает вот что

```
{ "hits": [ { "created_at": "2020-02-18T13:01:58.000Z", "title": ... и так далее }
```

Но при этом доступ есть только к "hits", при попытке получить например заголовок через `story.hits.title` не возвращает ничего. 
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `hits` - это массив. Нужно использовать индекс элемента, например, `story.hits[0].title`

Comment: В моём случае не работает :(  Если попытаться, в консоль выводит - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
this.stories = response;
```

замените на: 
`this.stories = response.hits;`

теперь в story хранятся элементы массива, а в story.title ваши тайтлы.

Comment: `response.data.hits`