# Как вытащить вложенный массив из json?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, api

Есть json

```
{
  hits:
    [
      {
        title: "Y Combinator",
        url: "http://ycombinator.com",
        author: "pg",
        points: 57,
        story_text: null,
      }
    ]
  }
```

Мне нужно его распарсить, но не получается вытащить данные из вложенного массива.

Понимаю, что наверное нужно как-то применить .map(), но не получается связать её с функцией подключения к API

```
        axios.get("http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story")
        .then(response => {
            this.stories = response.data;
```

Comment: уже есть такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084295/vue-js-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-api